# Change Magento Category Layout

Tags: php, magento

I need programmatically update page layout of thousands of categories in Magento + randomize products order. Here is the piece of code:

```
        /* @var $_childColorCategory Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $_childColorCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_childColorId);

        /* positions rand */
        $_positions = $_childColorCategory->getProductsPosition();
        if (count($_positions) > 1) {
            $_order = range(1, count($_positions));
            shuffle(&$_order);
            $_newPositions = array_combine(array_keys($_positions), $_order);
            $_childColorCategory->setPostedProducts($_newPositions);
        }

        $_childColorCategory
                ->setPageLayout('two_columns_right')
                ->save();
```

of course it's all in loop etc.

The issue is that layout is not being updated (order of nested products changed fine): I see in dashboard that all affected categories have right ('two_columns_right') layout, but it's not actually working on frontend before manual Save Button click in admin. If I click button (w/o making any changes) then layout becomes actually right on frontend and moreover - any further programmatic layout changes to that category works well. Any ideas? Thanks

P.S.
It's not a cache issue 100%.
Magento was updated to 1.7 - no luck.
Multistore setup (4 websites).

Answer (score 0):

In magento all layouts changes are in xml files, more information is in http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts

for categories layout you have anwser here
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16838/

BUT this is very bad idea to show randomize products because magento will be very slow.

Comment: why it must be slow? Of course I know how layouts in magento work, but I don't need all categories to be changed